# return range of indices from one list to get the values from other list

Tags: python, list, indices

I have two lists of equal size, one has the type of data (comes in succession):

```
types = ["vigi","vigi","fruits","fruits","fruits","nothing","nothing","nothing","nothing"]
```

The second list is about the data:

```
data = ["xx","tr","kl","ut","ew","uy","lp","eq","aq"]
```

from data list, I know that `"xx","tr"` are `"vigi"` and `"kl","ut","ew"` are `"fruits"` and so on.

What I need in each time divide the `data` into two datasets with:

```
data1 = data[indices for type "vigi"]
data2 = data[indices for the remaining (i.e. data for "fruits" and "nothing")]
```

A second time will have:

```
data1 = data[indices for type "fruits"]
data2 = data[indices for the remaining (i.e. data for "vigi" and "nothing")]
```

And so on ..

Any help with that please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function:

```
types = ["vigi","vigi","fruits","fruits","fruits","nothing","nothing","nothing","nothing"]
data = ["xx","tr","kl","ut","ew","uy","lp","eq","aq"]


data1 = [d for t, d in zip(types, data) if t == 'vigi']
data2 = [d for t, d in zip(types, data) if t != 'vigi']

print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Prints:

```
['xx', 'tr']
['kl', 'ut', 'ew', 'uy', 'lp', 'eq', 'aq']
```

---

Other version (that iterates over the lists only once):

```
types = ["vigi","vigi","fruits","fruits","fruits","nothing","nothing","nothing","nothing"]
data = ["xx","tr","kl","ut","ew","uy","lp","eq","aq"]

data1, data2 = [], []
for t, d in zip(types, data):
    if t == 'vigi':
        data1.append(d)
    else:
        data2.append(d)

print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can use `zip()`:

```
types = ["vigi","vigi","fruits","fruits","fruits","nothing","nothing","nothing","nothing"]
data = ["xx","tr","kl","ut","ew","uy","lp","eq","aq"]

data1 = [d for d,t in zip(data,types) if t == 'vigi']
data2 = [d for d,t in zip(data,types) if t in ['fruits','nothing']]

print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Output:

```
['xx', 'tr']
['kl', 'ut', 'ew', 'uy', 'lp', 'eq', 'aq']
```

---

Another way to go about this is to use `enumerate()`:

```
types = ["vigi","vigi","fruits","fruits","fruits","nothing","nothing","nothing","nothing"]
data = ["xx","tr","kl","ut","ew","uy","lp","eq","aq"]

data1 = [d for i,d in enumerate(data) if types[i] == 'vigi']
data2 = [d for i,d in enumerate(data) if types[i] in ['fruits','nothing']]

print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Output:

```
['xx', 'tr']
['kl', 'ut', 'ew', 'uy', 'lp', 'eq', 'aq']
```

But that iterates over the `data` list twice, when only one is necessary. Instead, to improve time complexity, use a for loop:

```
types = ["vigi","vigi","fruits","fruits","fruits","nothing","nothing","nothing","nothing"]
data = ["xx","tr","kl","ut","ew","uy","lp","eq","aq"]

data1 = []
data2 = []

for i,d in enumerate(data):
    if types[i] == 'vigi':
        data1.append(types[i])
    elif types[i] in ['fruits','nothing']:
        data2.append(types[i])

print(data1)
print(data2)
```

The same goes for the `zip()` option (see @AndrejKesely's answer for the for loop).

Comment: Might be only me, but it really irks me that this needs to zip and iterate twice. Maybe use a "normal" loop and append to each list as needed

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you wanted may be, but posting this as it may be helpful if you have a more complicated requirement in future:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> index = count()
>>> database = {key: [*group] for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x:types[next(index)])}
>>> database
{'vigi': ['xx', 'tr'],
 'fruits': ['kl', 'ut', 'ew'],
 'nothing': ['uy', 'lp', 'eq', 'aq']}
```

References:

1. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
2. [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Answer (score 0):

A variant on the single loop solution (see other answers). Relies on the fact that a boolean will become `0` or `1` when converted to `int`.  Might be considered hacky, but included for entertainment...

```
data1, data2 = [], []
out = (data2, data1)
for t, d in zip(types, data):
    out[t == 'vigi'].append(d)

print(data1)
print(data2)
```